# High resource usage while running CodeSchool angular.js tutorial

Tags: angularjs, macos, performance, memory, osx-yosemite

I'm using a **late-2011 MacBook Pro** with recently upgraded 16GB ram. Recently I'm experiencing **high system resource usage** when I'm doing the Angularjs.org Free Course provided by CodeSchool - "Shaping Up with Angular.js".

Angular.js is a framework for responsive web app, and, I believe the CodeSchool campus itself is also a **responsive** web app. I would expect it takes up a little bit more resources but what I'm experiencing is just too much:

- **Laggy** - the screen freeze while I type, after I finish typing the whole line of code (a few seconds), the words come out.
- **Spinning Beach Ball** - if I keep it too busy, such as while I'm going to scroll around and check my codes for possible mistake, the Spinning Beach Ball may appear.

But everything is just became such abnormal while I'm focus on that website. From the **Activity Monitor**, I observed that:

- **Memory** - http://campus.codeschool.com is taking up 1GB ~ 3GB memory consistently.
- **CPU** - something may be wrong with **WindowServer** process, as I've actually never seen it appearing on the top of my list before this.

Anyone has some clues on what's going wrong? Possible cause?